# How to use twitter plugin in cordova ios + iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, cordova-3

I'm new in cordova iOs development.I'm trying to integrate TWITTER plugin in my application.but did'nt get any success.I've x code version 4.6 and cordova version cordova-3.1.0.

[I'm following this link](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iOS/Twitter)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are not giving any code, so nobody can know, what is actually going on, but since the Twitter plugin you are linking to has not been touched for a year, I guess it simply won't run with the latest cordova. In the example, they are using cordova 1.7.

Comment: is there any plugin for latest cordova?

Comment: 2013-10-16 15:50:07.148 Twitter[23092:c07] ERROR: Method 'isTwitterAvailable:' not defined in Plugin 'TwitterPlugin'
2013-10-16 15:50:07.149 Twitter[23092:c07] -[CDVCommandQueue executePending] [Line 117] FAILED pluginJSON = [
  "TwitterPlugin1043189602",
  "TwitterPlugin",
  "isTwitterAvailable",
  [

  ]
]

Comment: The plugin isn't updated, fill an issue on github and maybe randy updates it. If not, you can follow the update guide and try to update it yourself. If you just want twitter posting, I think there is a social plugin updated that includes twitter and facebook posting